# Unable to git push julialang

Tags: github, julia

I'm trying to get the latest julia master commit. 
I instaled it via git clone, however, when I do

```
$ git push
```

It returns an exception:

```
 fatal: remote error: You can't push to git://github.com/JuliaLang/julia.git
 Use https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia.git
```

If I use the option given, git requires me a password.

Comment: Do you have permission to push to the repository?

Comment: Your problem was the use of git:// protocol, as I explain, *not* the "push as a contributor", as you selected: with the git:// protocol, you wouldn't be able to push, even if you were the owner of the repo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you probably don't actually want to *push* to the JuliaLang repository, but rather *pull* from it.

You `git pull` to fetch upstream changes and integrate them into your local repository.  So, for example, to update and rebuild Julia, you would `git pull && make clean && make` from within julia's directory while on the master branch.

You would only `git push` if you were a contributor submitting changes.  But even among contributors who have commit access, very few actually push directly to the master branch.  Most create branches, submit those, and then open a pull request for a review.  And for that workflow, you don't even need to be a contributor.  You can "fork" the project on Github, and then push to your forked repository online.  From there, you can open a pull request for review.

Answer (score 0):

git:// doesn't allow for authentication.

ssh or https does.

In the case of https, it is asking for your GitHub username and password.

See more at "[Git - the Protocols](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols)".

GitHub needs to know who you are, because only the owner (or a collaborator) has the right to push (while everybody can clone/pull from a public repo, which is why git:// works for cloning).
See "[Permission levels for a user account repository](https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-a-user-account-repository)".

Note: here [github.com/JuliaLang](https://github.com/JuliaLang) is an organization, which means only the owner and members/teams can push to a repo declared in that organization.
Se more at "[Permission levels for an organization repository](https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-an-organization-repository)".

Comment: and to @jwodder, fine I see what's the error. Now I would like to know why the developers have this issue concerning julia :P

Comment: @user2820579 I just realized that JuliaLang is a GitHub organization. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm just getting involved on Git's public policies.

Comment: @user2820579 no problem. I was just surprised you selected the wrong answer, that is one which has nothing to do with the issue you described in your question.